# recursive function to outputs the minimum number of the array

Tags: c++, recursion

i was asked to create a recursive function that outputs the minimum number of the array that the user enters. the problem is when run the code the output is funny and the cout is repeated many times with weird values.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    void recursiveMinimum(int i, int f, int *a, int min)
    {
        if(a[i]<min)
        {
            min=a[i];
        }
        i++;
        if (i<f)
        { 
            recursiveMinimum(i, f, a, min);
        }
        cout<<"the minimum number is "<<min<<endl;
     }

     void main ()
     {
         int *a, b=1000, f;
         a= new int [b];
         cout<<"please enter the array, enter '1000' without the quotes to stop"<<endl;
         for(int i=0; i<b; i++)
         {
            cin>>a[i];
            if (a[i]==1000)
             {
                 a[i]=NULL;
                 f=i;
                 break;
             }
        }
         recursiveMinimum(0, f, a, a[0]);
         system("pause");
     }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i don't understand why the "cout" in the function repeats many times although it is supposed to only work once, also the minimum changes every cout

Comment: Probably "where can i get a non-crappy C++ book?".  The one he has is gonna scar him for life.

Comment: thanks for the sarcasm sir...but the sad truth is that not everyone in this world is a professional like you...i am sorry that i am trying to learn and seeking help.

Comment: @AmrShrief: I don't blame you -- i blame whoever wrote the books/tutorials you're learning from.  They're teaching you horrible practices.  You'd do well to find a less crappy source.

Comment: It looks like you are missing your "base case". Which is a term used in recursion for when the recursive function should stop calling itself and return.

Comment: By combining the printing of the value and the finding of the value into a single method, there is more room for error, especially in recursion. Consider having it return the minimum value (and definitely implement the "base case" @Beed mentioned)

Comment: @cHao it's an assignment for the data structure course i am studying in the university...so it's not an optional luxury for me to change it. you could have said a positive feedback better than this negativity anyway.

Comment: beed & BenKnoble  thanks a lot i'll try that

Comment: You're on the right track. I would recommend reading up on recursion and trying to gain an understanding of it. I assume it is covered in your textbook and course notes. There are many tutorials online as well.

Comment: yeah actually i try to make use of youtube a lot in these kind of stuff...thanks a lot for your time and your kind encouraging words.

Comment: Also note that *recursion* is most probably not the right technique for this problem. Compilers are sometimes able to transform tail-recursion into a loop, but your implementation does not exhibit the qualities of a tail-recursive function, which means that this will cause a function call (and additional stack space) for each element in the array, requiring O(N) space on top of the O(N) time, where a simple loop would be O(1) space and O(N) time [most probably with a lower constant factor]

Comment: @DavidRodriguez-dribeas thanks for the useful feedback...the thing is that i am only doing this because i had it as an assignment...it's not for professional work or anything...but of course it is nice to know that fact...thanks

Comment: It'd be pretty simple to make a recursive version that only needed O(log N) space for the call stack.  But doing so would make it no longer tail-recursive.  Recursion isn't as good with lists as with, say, trees.

Comment: @cHao: you can tweak the implementation to use tail-recursion and get O(1) space, but you have to be careful and it is not something that I would expect a student to get right… well, that and also that for this particular algorithm the loop is as simple if not simpler than the recursive solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know C++ very well, but doesn't cout get called many times, specifically each time the recursive function gets called? Here is the updated recursiveMinimum function:

```
void recursiveMinimum(int i, int f, int *a, int min)
{
    if(a[i]<min)
    {
        min=a[i];
    }
    i++;
    if (i<f)
    { 
        recursiveMinimum(i, f, a, min);
    } else {
        cout<<"the minimum number is "<<min<<endl;
        return;
    }
 }
```

I moved the print statement into an else statement. When I isn't less than F, which should only happen when you have reached the end of the array, the program will print the minimum number and end.

Comment: No problem. Also, don't worry about "stupid" mistakes. Recursion is one of the most difficult subjects in computer science. Also, everyone makes stupid mistakes **all** the time.

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging words :)

Comment: Stackoverflow can sometimes be a cold place. However, there are people who aren't negative and horrible all the time! :D